# Powershell to find folder/subfolder and then write if condition to perform action only if folder A is greater than folder B

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Basically need to write powershell which give me list of sub directory's.
in my sub directory my folder structure is like 101.10.1 , 101.10.2 , 101.10.3
now want to write if condition which take a higher directory from folder (101.10.3)  and rhen  remove ms sql 2005 application.

something like this

```
    ****$path = "C:\abc\xyzh\Versions"
$contents = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | sort | Select-Object -Last 10
$contents.Name
$condition = $contents.Name
if ( $condition -gt "$path/$condition" )
{
        # do something"
    }****
```

Comment: And what is your question? :)

Comment: comparing number STRINGS is done as strings, not numbers. [*grin*] if all your paths are `digits.digits.digits`, you can use the `[version]` type accelerator to do your comparison. interestingly, that also works for ipv4 addresses ...

Comment: Confusing... What is it you want to do? Find the folder with the highest version number in its name and then do something, or create a new folder with versionnumber +1 and then do something, or...

Answer (score 0):

Say you have:

```
    101.10.1
    101.10.2
    101.10.211
    101.10.3
    101.10.323
    101.10.4
    101.10.5
    101.10.610
```

If you run this command:

```
gci |  sort -property name | ?{$_.name -gt '101.10.3'} | %{ echo "dosomething $_"  }
```

You get:

```
dosomething 101.10.323
dosomething 101.10.4
dosomething 101.10.5
dosomething 101.10.610
```

Now, you can change echo "dosomething $_" to another useful command.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro Bermúdez really appreciate for your help.
 I  am quite  new to PowerShell but using above command i can able to list down directories now i want to write if loop for eg in above folder folder listing folder 101.10.610 is higher then only run  Microsoft sql removal command . do you have any sample powershell
Thanks in Advance